# Should money be paid as a motivation to testers and developers for detecting and producing bugs?

Tags: work-experience, relationships, productivity

I read an idea for increasing productivity in a company. It went like this:

> Have a certain fund that will be a bonus. Say $100,000. For each *tangible* bug found, the testers get paid $5 - $15. Whatever's left over at the end of the month/year goes to the developers.

It seems like a wonderful enough idea in theory, though I'm not sure how well it will work in practice. The obvious consequence of this is that it promotes antagonism between developers and testers. The bug business becoming a zero-sum game.

Is the antagonism a bad thing? How will it affect productivity, and more importantly the organisation? Personal experience will be highly appreciated.

P.S: I'm not in any managerial position (still in college) though I do have plans for a few software startups when I graduate.

Comment: The core idea here is that it's better to place a team in competition than collaboration. And no, even when you ignore the practical problems with this plan, that's a recipe for failure.

Comment: It motivates both teams to work harder. They get rewarded for doing their job better.

Comment: @TobiAlafin see the video I linked in my answer for why it does not motivate them at all. Money alone is a terrible motivator, despite what a lot of people think.

Comment: maybe for the first run, then I'm going to sit there knowing my colleague got a massive bonus and I didn't even though we worked equally hard, that's not going to do my morale any good

Comment: I up-voted the question because it is a really important concept to get right. But, please, take the advice of all of these responders who have a lot of diverse experience and backgrounds, and who all agree that this is an idea with MANY harmful side effects that could have a far more negative impact than any good that might come from it.

Comment: Bug is a determination. You think that software behaves in a certain "incorrect" way and it's important for the business. In reality it may turn out that what you think is wrong or it's okay, because business needs are not impacted. It goes a long way to prove both of these, and if money is involved, there will be trench wars. New feature development will be stagnated due to fear. A and A+ people will leave shortly.

Comment: Daily WTF has an excellent story of something similar to this and you can see what happened: [The Defect Black Market](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Defect-Black-Market)

Comment: This question kind of shows the limits of ultra-competitive thinking.

Comment: Aaahhh the gamificiation of development and debugging! Game anything and people will start playing it, manipulating it, cheating it, hacking it, beating it,...

Comment: @FixedPoint and QA/developers tend to be GOOD at games. Usually better than the managers who make the rules for the games...

Comment: What motivation do programmers have to fix the bugs? Once the bug has been marked as a bug, it's safer NOT to fix it - we won't introduce new bug, and money is lost anyway.

Comment: Why on earth use a zero sum solution? At least find a positive sum solution (points for software that passed client validation). With that as foundation you can then think on how to distribute the benefits in a good way.

Comment: I have decided to accept the answers I've seen, and I've dropped this as an idea that I'll use in future. Erik's video convinced me.

Comment: Mandatory Dilbert reference: http://dilbert.com/strip/1995-11-13

Comment: This exact scenario has happened in history (can't remember where), but more simply where devs got paid for each bug they squash. This mushroomed into devs producing and fixing a huuge amount of "bugs"

Comment: Instead of money how about using something silly and trivial like cupcakes?

Comment: What about the situation where a dev finds a bug and fixes it but it goes into Jira or Bugzilla anyway so that QA knows to test it? This idea is too black and white and too "us vs them."

Comment: Will cupcakes even work?

Comment: In my experience cupcakes would work significantly better if the idea will work at all. This is because it promotes a friendly comp where one side can rub it in the other's face without being terrible terrible people. It would have the potential to run like a friendly tournament rather than, say, the hunger games. Key word potential. If you're planning on going for managing, you badly need to learn the difference.

Comment: @Jeff: cupcakes have problems too, particularly if the testing team finds many bugs. Incipient diabetes, arterial blockages, bad knees (oh, how I know about bad knees!), etc, blah. Don't do it! Just send ME the cupcakes and **I** will take care of them for you. It's for your own good... :-)

Comment: [Classic Dilbert](http://dilbert.com/strip/1995-11-13). Yeah, dat's right - I'm gonna write me a mini-van!

Comment: @BobJarvis huh, I never thought about it that way. Shipping $100,000 worth of cupcakes to you right now. In all seriousness though, I've been on teams that did something similar (it was actually individual team members buying the other team donuts if they did better than us). It worked really nicely until we started ODing on sugar...

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=dilbert+write+me+a+minivan  when your idea is exactly from a Dilbert cartoon…

Comment: Personally, if you put that system in on me, I'd start a betting pool on who would be fighting in the parking lot, and how soon.  This is just about the dumbest plan I've ever heard of.

Comment: It's a recipe for disaster. The only situation in which I can see it _maybe_ working is one where the specifications are 100% written, 100% updated whenever even the smallest design change is decided, and 100% usable to determine with certainty what the expected behavior of the code is in different contexts. If the situation is not like that (and usually it's not) you will now be looking at continuous arguments about whether it's a bug or not. Or to put it in another way, now testers have a (financial!) interest in developers making bugs, and developers have interest in testers missing bugs.

Comment: Bonus for producing bugs? SUBSCRIBE!!!

Comment: The new title "bonus for producing bugs" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Lol. I'm not the one who changed it.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

> I read an idea for increasing productivity in a company. It went like
>   this:
>
> *Have a certain fund, that will be a bonus. Say $100,000. For each tangible bug found, the testers get paid $5 - $15. Whatever's left
>   over at the end of the month/year goes to the Devs.*
>
> It seems like a wonderful enough idea in theory, though I'm not sure
>   how well it will work in practice. The obvious consequence of this, is
>   that it promotes antagonism between Devs and testers. The bug business
>   becoming a zero sum game.
>
> Is the antagonism a bad thing? How will it affect productivity, and
>   more importantly the organisation? Personal experience will be highly
>   appreciated.

(I cringe when I read "motivational" schemes like this.)

Perhaps the author of this idea defines "productivity" differently than I would.

The goal of most companies producing software is to make money, and perhaps maximize the amount of money they make. The goal of a bug bounty system is less clear, and certainly has nothing to do with productivity. A lot of time would be spent trying to get bonus money, and little time would be spent trying to ship the software (which is how the company makes money).

Imagine a company having one developer and one tester.

If you were the developer, your optimal strategy would be to withhold all software from the tester until there were no bugs remaining at all, or until there was no time in the schedule for the tester to find any.

I worked at a company that rewarded developers with praise, rather than money, and that was exactly the strategy used by one developer. Builds were released to QA every 2 weeks. And every other Friday, we had a full-team meeting where the bug count in the current build was announced. If a developer ever had zero bugs, that developer was singled out and praised for doing a great job.

One developer decided to game the system. She would hold the build (always having reasonable excuses) until just before the weekly meeting. She then released the build, the bug count report was run, and "magically" she had a zero bug count just in time for the meeting.

While she was a good developer, her code wasn't any better than most others. Her cleverness was in manipulating the system to her advantage.

I currently work in a shop that punishes Developers for the number of bugs attributed to their work during a project. They are expected to "improve" their bug count from the prior year. This is part of their MBOs, and part of what goes into their annual bonus payout.

Unsurprisingly, they have taken a long time to produce the first testable build for QA. And they asked that QA spend a lot of time testing in the Dev environment (where bug reports cannot be written). They have been given every chance to produce fewer bugs in the reporting system, and hence to maximize their bonus.

The Product Manager has even decided to change many bug reports to "enhancement requests" so as not to impact developer MBOs. His argument was "well, the developers haven't fully developed that feature, so they will enhance it when they have time".

If I were getting paid "by the bug" I could find a ton of bugs quite easily, no matter how good the developer. (I've been doing this work for almost 30 years). I'd focus initially on the low hanging fruit and skip anything that was time consuming at all. My bug reports would be minimal and not very helpful - basically whatever it took to enter the bug report in the system and get the cash.

The result would be a lot of superficial bug reports that were "just tangible enough" and the software would inevitably be left with some major critical bugs. I can't imagine the system would ever ship.

The developers would focus all their time and attention on new code. There would be absolutely no financial benefit in fixing any bugs that were already found. And they would be given incentive to produce tiny, insignificant releases. If they produce a release containing only a single line of perfect code, they get a $100k bonus! Why add any tricky features at all?

Both teams would argue vehemently about each and every bug report and if it was truly a "tangible" bug or not. (That's a nice and fuzzy term. I'd love to hear a team try to define it concretely). These sorts of arguments don't set the stage for anything I'd call productivity.

And neither testers nor developers would spend any time on anything else. No meetings, no documentation, no customer support, no helping others, no prep for shipping. Hey, if it were important, there would be cash attached to it, right?

And this last part is significant. For knowledge workers, often attaching cash bonuses to tasks they intrinsically feel are important is a big disincentive. If you want a greater understanding of the kinds of dysfunction that can arise from these sorts of incentive systems, I highly recommend you read [Measuring and Managing Performance in Organizations by Robert D. Austin.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DY3KQX6)

**In short, this is a terrible idea.**

Most good software companies recognize the folly of such a plan and try to stay away from this sort of system. Most software companies understand that releasing software with zero bugs isn't a realistic goal, and that it's more important to release software in a timely manner.

Comment: 'Enhancement requests' is a good point here — as a developer, if you deduct money from my pay for every bug, it makes it in my interest to fight tooth & nail over the spec: *"the story never said the Date of Birth field couldn't be in the future. This isn't a bug, it's an additional story."* In addition to rewarding devs for working slower and for being less helpful to QA team, you're also incentivising them to ignore common sense and needing everything documented by the Product Owner/Analyst to the Nth degree.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/thats-not-a-bug-its-a-feature-request/

Comment: Adding to all of this, I can imagine there would be an hanging pole outside the developers' office for anyone who dares refactoring old code, leaving the codebase in a complete mess because "If it isn't buggy, don't even try to touch it!"

Comment: "One developer decided to game the system." - Protesting via "golem labour" or just really into praise? Either way, I think she's a genius, and would like to find a way to incentivise her to being on my side.

Comment: While the setup described in the OP is indeed pretty terrible, an actual, proper bug bounty may be okay.  Setting up an adversarial competition between development and QA is _not_ a proper bug bounty, however.  A better way to do it is to just award your QA testers a bonus for each bug they find.  And perhaps also your developers for each reported bug that they fix.

Comment: @aroth - I'm gonna write me a new minivan this afternoon! http://dilbert.com/strip/1995-11-13 (be careful what you pay for - you won't get what you might expect)

Comment: @WorkerDrone - Fair enough.  Though 'be careful you don't hire corrupt/unethical developers' seems like an equally plausible interpretation.

Comment: I think @aroth was spot on with his remarks. Albeit the OP was not likely to do well with his setup, this could be framed better. Even this posts comments could easily be taken out with a simple framework (such as only major/critical bugs receive bounty, pre-existing bugs only, and not making it a competition between devs and testers).

Comment: Date of birth _can_ be in the future. The obvious case when the date of birth is estimated, it could be 8 months in the future. The less obvious case, if the mother crosses the date line in exactly the right way at the right time, the date of birth (which is the current date at the time and in the place where the baby is born) can be "next day" after crossing the date line. Or easier, giving birth just after midnight in one time zone, then moving to just before midnight on the previous day in another time zone.

Answer (score 132):

It seems like a dreadful idea. Here's a few things that will happen, *in addition* to your developers and testers starting to hate each other and yourself for introducing this:

- Everyone will focus on low hanging fruit. This means that QA will start reporting all sorts of stuff that's actually fine but might be construed to be "buggy" in hopes of getting paid, while Devs will focus all their work on making sure there are no obvious bugs and a lot less on making sure there are no complex, structural bugs.
- Some people will gang up and a dev will intentionally introduce a ton of bugs, then send it to a specific QA to "find" them, then split the cash.
- Some of your employees will be insulted because you think they only value their job if they get a bonus for it. They will probably work *less* hard and produce *more* junk because of this.
- Communication between members of the team will break down because of increased antagonism. It's now actually a plus for the devs to *not* help QA do their job better, because any bugs that go into production unnoticed means they *get paid more.*
- Devs will dislike each other, because every bug one dev introduces will cost all of them money.

This is just off the top of my head. Don't ever try to motivate programmers and QAs with money, it only turns out terrible. Their jobs run on intrinsic motivation.

Also, please have a look at this animated TED-talk about drive and motivation, as it explains much better why any setup that involves motivating smart people with money will fail terribly:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6XAPnuFjJc

Comment: +1 I think it's also worth stating that you're in a market for developers and are competing with other firms. The negative externalities from this proposition will lead to a situation where the good developers leave and the lemons are left. QA will be pleased as the change in the composition in the quality of the software engineers will lead to larger bonuses for them under this scheme. This is one of the most destructive ideas I've come across.

Comment: +1 This is likely to breed hostility among the team that could even go beyond the tech team and QA. Developers will argue about who introduced a bug and whether it's a bug in the first place or possibly a result of badly written specification, bad design etc.

Comment: I looked at the video(network was bad, so it took a while). I was completely sold on it. Suffice it to say, that it has inspired another question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49928/discussion-between-erik-and-djechlin).

Comment: The colluding argument is very real. I read about a case where devs served testers some cool loopholes and caveats, they split the bonuses. I think the scheme was discovered because they went too big, too often, i.e. super hidden bugs started appearing and discovered at a suspicious rates.

Comment: "QA's will start reporting all sorts of stuff that's actually fine but might be construed to be 'buggy'" The QA staff where I work do this anyway. Half the "bugs" the QA's open on my project are design advice ("Put a loading spinner on this page"), grammar corrections (which are usually wrong), and things that are working as intended but not according to the QA's expectations. A few times we've nearly overlooked possibly world-ending bugs because of this. If they were getting paid bonuses for this, they'd flood us with spurious garbage bugs.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere There's a step missing. The QA team will also be stripped of the people that value quality over reward. The remaining QA members will be happy with situation, since they get more low hanging fruit which means more money for them.

Comment: @Torisuda: While it is unfortunate that the QA people are wrong about the grammar issues, I would certainly consider mistakes (orthography, grammar, whatever) in UI text to be quality issues that need to be caught at some point in the QA process.

Comment: Here is a possibly true anecdote about this sort of situation: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Defect-Black-Market

Comment: @Torisuda, QA interpreting the requirement differently than the devs is a clear sign that the requirement is wrong. It always means however that the people who came up with the requirement need to be consulted about which is the correct interpretation and then the actions taken depend on that answer. This is a valid bug to raise and should never be dismissed as well that is the correct way. I have seen many a project saved because this discrepancy in what was meant was brought up and QA was in fact correct about what the requirement meant. I am always grateful when QA raises this kind of bug.

Comment: @HLGEM: it's nice if QA catches it, but it's a lot better if there's enough communication that the devs realize it before they build it :)

Comment: Yes I agree many, if not most, devs need to talk to the users/stakeholders/BAs more while designing and not make these sort of misinterpretations, but I have seen all too many take the requirement at face value never asking appropriate, even obvious, questions.  Further, part of the reason for QA is to have someone with a different perspective look at how things were done. This is why having devs do their own QA is a bad idea. It is exactly these things that the dev will never find because he knows what he thinks the requirement is.

Comment: @HLGEM We outsource to a QA firm overseas, so the QA staff are missing a lot of domain knowledge and context; for that reason their interpretation is rarely correct, though explaining it to them does sometimes help me understand the requirement better myself.

Comment: @Torisuda when you made your first comment, this was the first thing I wondered about. From the times I've seen it tried, I've concluded that it's not worth it to have QA overseas. It's really something you should have in-house.

Comment: Or you could try providing them with the domain knowledge. That is what we did with our overseas QA. We spent the money to bring a couple of their senior people here for a couple of months to learn. That paid huge dividends.

Comment: Yeah, at the very least they should have excellent domain knowledge. And a good grasp of the native language of the app. You can't be a good QA without it.

Comment: @Erik From my experience, I agree that it would be much better to have in-house QA. Unfortunately, this was a system that was in place long before I started and will probably be in place long after I leave. They do have decent English knowledge, but there are dialectal differences that cause some confusion, and their domain knowledge is decent but has gaps that aren't easily rectified since they're overseas.

Comment: @HLGEM That's a good idea. I don't think our company has the resources for it but it's something I might try pitching. Even a few video chats with key people might help.

Answer (score 23):

This makes as much sense as having a ship's crew split into teams, those who do propulsion and those who navigate, compete in a race with each other, on the same ship.

I refuse to have an antagonistic relationship with my testers. I value them. They make me a better coder.

I also respect the creativity their job demands of them. Which is why I think money is the wrong motivator here. [Studies have shown](https://tedsummaries.com/2014/06/06/dan-pink-the-puzzle-of-motivation/) that unless a job is practically mindless, cash incentives actually, measurably, slow people down.

Creative work isn't best motivated by money. Its best motivators are:

> autonomy – the desire to direct our own lives 
> mastery – the urge to get better, or develop skills 
> and purpose – the need to do what we do for reasons bigger than ourselves

That's right, choices, opportunities to improve, and teamwork would work better than money.

QA is a creative job. The task really is to think of what the developers didn't think of. This is why QA should automate. Once a test is thought of it shouldn't be "performed" again and again like a Broadway play. It should be automated so QA can stop thinking about it and think about the next test. QA should be filled with your most talented developers. Because they're trying to out think your other team of developers.

Some don't think so. Some think of QA as a dumping ground for less talented developers. If you've been doing that, your priorities are backwards. Challenge your best developers to modernize your testing and make sure people know that QA is where you put the best.

If that money is still burning a hole in your pocket use it on training or if need be, severance packages.

We don't do mindless work here.

Answer (score 14):

> Have a certain fund, that will be a bonus. Say $100,000. For each tangible bug found, the testers get paid $5 - $15. Whatever's left over at the end of the month/year goes to the Devs.

That's horrible. For all the reasons in the other answers and for the fact that it does not pass this very simple test:

- What if all your employees are great and no bugs are found?

  Production works perfectly and all the money will go to the DEVS
- What if all your employees are crap?

  Production just burned to the ground because of the bugs, but hey, who cares, the money will go to the DEVS.

Even if money *were* a motivator in our business, this would be horribly wrong.

Take the money and hire somebody who is really good at writing specs and planning projects with manageable deadlines. Both DEV and QA will be way happier than any money could ever make them.

Comment: Good point to suggest alternative uses for $100,000 fund. There are probably a few other choice uses of this much money to make a team of devs and QAs more productive. Although I think it would go off-topic to start brainstorming them.

Comment: "Production just burned to the ground because of the bugs, but hey, who cares, the money will go to the DEVS." - in theory that's the incentive for QA to do better, because they will get paid for not letting production get burned to the ground.

Answer (score 10):

It may be apocryphal, but I was given a similar example in the 1980's when covering the "Law of Unintended Consequences" as part of a BPR course.

The example concerned a factory production line where the quality control department were incentivised by how many rejects they made. The production department was similarly incentivised according to how few rejects they produced.

The net effect was that quality control rejected more products than previously and production took longer to produce "perfect" items, so overall output went down while costs went up due to the incentive payments. Quality was unaffected.

Answer (score 6):

It works badly. I haven't seen it with devs and testers. But the justice department in NZ at one point rewarded periodic detention wardens for each detainee they breached. It went from one breach in a bad week, to some detainees getting 6 breaches in a day and ending up in prison over it. Eventually a warden got hurt.

I doubt it would go that far since it's not the same amount and less volatile people (I would think), but it breeds bad blood between the groups who are already at odds due to their roles.

Comment: I have no clue what it means to breach a detainee.

Comment: I'm guessing 'breach a detainee' means 'make an official record that a detainee breached a rule'

Comment: @emory My understanding is that it was an official writeup and if a detainee got 3 within their sentence, they were arrested, taken back to court and resentenced to a prison term.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have already sufficiently stated that your idea is bad TM. So I won't further repeat that, and instead mention what you'd need to change to improve the idea.

You're trying to attach money to what's ultimately number on a paper. That number won't create any money. To make things worse, the number you want to use is mostly random: A product that never had any bugs suddenly has 50, all of them typos in the documentation. A bug that messes up the highlight color of 200 items becomes 200 bugs. As soon as you ask some people to make the number magically go up, that number is a completely useless imaginary number. And on top of it all you'll waste tens of thousands of dollars in wages with absolutely pointless meetings where people argue what is and what isn't a bug.

If you want to attach bonuses or other rewards to numbers on a paper, these numbers must be directly linked to actual money earned by the company - one common example is bonus being linked to profit in a trading company.

Answer (score 3):

As has been suggested in the 'cupcake' comments under your question, some forms of gamification can work. How about assigning a trophy for the 'Best Bug' found during a certain period, assigned by votes from **both teams together**?

In a healthy development environment there is a shared 'awe' between testers and developers about people (usually the testers) finding those pesky bugs that can only be reproduced under certain conditions, about that intermittent bug that has been pestering you for months, about something very simple that a developer overlooked, etc.<sup>*</sup>

The trophy should be something very simple, because it's not about its intrinsic value: a small sign, a cupcake, a bar of chocolate.

<sup>* That last example is not about finding a bug, but causing a bug. In that case the prize means friendly mockery. You do need a culture for that where your colleagues recognize that everybody makes mistakes.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I think the outcome would be detrimental. It's both against common sense practices of both developing and testing.
Zero bugs found doesn't mean that software is good.
It could be to complex to test or QA could skip some testing.
Even zero bugs found, extensive testing process and great quality of code doesn't mean that product is good. If the requirements were messed, the software can be terrible for client.

Playing against that system could be extremely easy.
For devs: late builds.
For testers: concentration on trivial bugs. 
With late builds, early testing is impossible. Little time for testing and gratification for number of bugs? Testers concentrate on trivial bugs, like misspelled labels or some non-critical cases.

If you want to know if the product is good, just ask your client.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short. Developers and testers are working on same boat - your company.

It is easy to critisize developer for a bug they produce but it is hard to reward them for bugs they haven't produced.

If the bug made it to final build and customer reported it who was to be blamed? Developer for writing the bug or tester for not catching it?

This causes the tension between developers and testers by default. Your idea puts aditional tension between the two. You really do not want that.

If you have friendly workspace and want to reward the bug-catching split the budget to everyone fairly, make a list of developers and for every bug the developer shall pay $1 to the bank. Organise the Xmas party and use the bank to reward whole team. Ensure, it is more fun than reward/punishment and that nobody takes it (too) serious. Reward both the "worst" and "best" among developers and testers.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the incentive at best seems useless and at worse harmful. If you have a devoted QA team you already have set aside funds to find bugs as that will be a big part of their job description. There won't be much added antagonism between the two as there will be more toward the policy itself.  If you are actually worried about the problem that much to throw money at your current employees with strings attached, it would be better to hire someone where you need them in either QA or dev.

Where this could go really wrong is on the dev side is that you'll see a drop in releases for fear they'll get paid less because of new bugs and on the QA side you could see much longer review phases due to testers wanting some extra pay. Not saying this *will* happen, just that it's a possibility.

Nobody wants bugs in their final product, but the will happen. As a manager there are much better ways to make sure less bugs exist in the code such as having realistic goals and time tables and allowing facilitation for better development like code reviews.

Comment: But they aren't getting paid less. I'm not deducting their agreed upon salary. I'm giving them a bonus based on how many bugs were absent in their code. If longer review periods mean a little better quality, why not. There should be a policy imposed timeframe for review though.

Comment: @TobiAlafin: They're getting paid less than they would if no bugs were found. It's human nature to think of this as a loss.